# Android gridview item change

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to change the `GridView` item background in `onCreateView()`, after setting the adapter. I tried this way:

```
final int numVisibleChildren = gv_categories.getAdapter().getCount();       

    for ( int i = 0; i < numVisibleChildren; i++ ) {
        int positionOfView = i + 1;

        try {   
            if (positionOfView == Integer.valueOf(m_transactionItem.getIcon())) { 
                View view = gv_categories.getChildAt(i);
                int nColor = Color.parseColor(m_transactionItem.getcolor());
                if(view != null) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("GridviewItemErr", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

But `view` is always `null`. This is my custom adapter that contains an `ImageView` and the `TextView`:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
int id = 0;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewHolder holder;

public static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView text;
    private ImageView icon;
    private int mId;

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        mId = id;
    }


}

public CategoryAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return mAllIcons.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        id++;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_grid_item, null);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGrid_Item_Category);
        //holder.icon.setId(id);
        holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGrid_Item_Category);
        //holder.text.setId(id);
        holder.setId(id);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.icon.setImageResource(mAllIcons[position]);
    holder.text.setText(mCategNames[position]);


    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}

private Integer[] mAllIcons = {
        R.drawable.icon_1_prijevoz_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_2_putovanje_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_3_hoteli_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_4_odrzavanje_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_5_zabava_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_6_kucne_potrepstine_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_7_odjeca_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_8_trgovina_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_9_rezije_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_10_restorani_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_11_slobodno_vrijeme_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_12_luksuz_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_13_odmor_i_rekreacija_neselktirane,
        R.drawable.icon_14_ostalo_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_15_prihod_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_16_stalni_prihodi_neselektirane,
        R.drawable.icon_17_default_neselektirane
};

private String[] mCategNames = {
        "Prijevoz", "Putovanje",
        "Hoteli", "Održavanje",
        "Zabava", "Kućne potrepštine",
        "Odjeća", "Trgovina",
        "Režije", "Restorani",
        "Slobodno vrijeme", "Luksuz",
        "Odmor i rekreacija",
        "Ostalo", "Prihod",
        "Stalni prihod", "Default",
};
}
```

I tried many other ways to do this but I cant figure out how to get "visible" GridView items.

**NOTE:**

The background needs to be changed when fragment is created, not in `onItemClickedListener` or `onScrollListener` or like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem arises from the fact that you are trying to reference the grid's views before your ImageAdapter had created them, if you wish really to set the background color at the time of `onCreateView()` and not at the time of calling `getView()`, I would suggest that you use `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` , to make sure that the gridview had been properly inflated before calling getChildAt(i), your code would look something like this:

```
gv_categories.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //At this point the layout is complete and the 
        //dimensions of myView and any child views are known.
        final int numVisibleChildren = gv_categories.getAdapter().getCount();       
        for ( int i = 0; i < numVisibleChildren; i++ ) {
            int positionOfView = i + 1;
            try {   
                if (positionOfView == Integer.valueOf(m_transactionItem.getIcon())) { 
                View view = gv_categories.getChildAt(i);
                int nColor = Color.parseColor(m_transactionItem.getcolor());
                    if(view != null) {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("GridviewItemErr", e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, to work with 'Adapter', I don't think you need touch the view directly at creating time. Just change the dataset of the Adapter, and when system call

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

You could just either create a new view or reuse a converted view.

Another scenario is that data changes at runtime, please make sure the updating happens in worker thread. And call :

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged()
```

to notify UI thread to change the UI correspondingly.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear enough, i need to change item background when fragment is first created...

Comment: ic. I think it should be doable. For me, I guess just need change the data which ties to the UI item in background thread, and call 'notifyDataSetChanged()', then system will call getView() again and you could update the color/text/... and any other attributes there. Hopefully, this is the answer you are seeking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `ListAdapter` items from inside the `getView()` method, based on the position. Since the `View`s are recycled, don't forget to revert the changes (e.g. reset your background to default) if the position doesn't match the one you want to change.

`AdapterView`s such as `GridView` lazy-load their items dynamically from their `Adapter`s based on the layout and scroll position, so they are not populated during the initial `View` population.